Alien movie with rope like tails
I watched this movie when I was like 10 maybe, so 20ish years ago, but it had aliens and humans in pink slimy like pods (but not pods, like a wall of pods) and the aliens had rope like tails. I can't find it anywhere

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Were the aliens in the pods too, or just the humans?  Were the humans being transformed into aliens, incubating aliens, or were they food?  Were the aliens' tails prehensile?

Is it possible that you're recalling a scene from The Matrix? As much as it pains me to realise it's more than 20 years old now.
No aliens, but the machines have a semi-organic look and could easily be recalled as alien. The scene where Keanu Reeves as Neo wakes up in the real world has him in a pod full of pink goo, in one of several massive walls of identical pods, tended by machines with long, tail-like tentacles.




First thought that came to my mind too.
